# Subclassing AFHTTPSessionManager and making it a singleton in swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, afnetworking-2

I am new to swift with a good objective-c background and I am trying to write a web handler by subclassing **AFHTTPSessionManager** and converting it to a singleton. During my initialization of the self, I am getting a weird error which I am unable to solve `(Must call a designated initializer of the subclass 'AFHTTPSessionManager')`- Its also commented in the code below in order to help understand where its occurring. Also please suggest if this is the right way to implement a singleton.

```
class XYZWebHandler: AFHTTPSessionManager
{
    internal static let _sharedInstance = XYZWebHandler()

    class func sharedInstance() -> XYZWebHandler
    {
        return _sharedInstance
    }

    init(baseURL url: NSURL!)
    {
        super.init(baseURL: url) //Must call a designated initializer of the subclass 'AFHTTPSessionManager'
        setup()
    }

    override init(baseURL url: NSURL!, sessionConfiguration configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration!)
    {
        super.init(baseURL: url, sessionConfiguration: configuration)
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func setup()
    {
        requestSerializer = AFJSONRequestSerializer()
        responseSerializer = AFJSONResponseSerializer()
    }
```

}

Thank you very much for your help. Looking forward to hearing from you soon

Comment: Just a reminder but why dont u use [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) instead? Its made for `Swift` by the creator of `AFNetworking` too, `AFNetworking` is made mostly for `Obj-C`

Comment: Never worked with it hence dont know much about it. Will look into it then, thanks ;)

Comment: Basically its not much diff than the other one also :D just that they combine  the success and error block into 1

Answer (score 0):

1) Your singleton needs refining - see some good examples in swift here : https://github.com/hpique/SwiftSingleton/tree/master/Singleton

2) As for the error : Swift has two types on initialisers : designated and convenience - the latter is secondary and doesn't have to be supplied. As for the designated - it's primary initialiser that inits all properties, it's A MUST for every class, and also have to call a designated one from his immediate super class.
In light of this - you need to go to AFHTTPSessionManager and find an appropriate designated initialiser that creates a session and store it in _sharedInstance. You might also be a cast (as!) there in this store. e.g.

```
_sharedInstance = AFHTTPSessionManager(baseURL: NSURL("http://your_url.com")) as! XYZWebHandler
```

3) I join the recommenation for Alamo - it's newer :)

GOOD LUCK.